# Turn lowercase to uppercase and viceversa

Tags: sql, postgresql

The title is self-descriptive, given a string in SQL I need to replace the lowercase to uppercase and viceversa without using the `regexp_replace` function or anything related with regular expressions. I am using PostgreSQL 9.6.

The transformation is for the password_transaction field of the following code.

```
INSERT INTO
    Transaccio
SELECT
    id,
    date_transaction,
    iban,
    amount_money,
    time_transaction,
    password_transaction,
    was_ok,
    credit_card,
    currency_code,
    md5(iban || currency_code)
FROM
    Import;
```

Comment: We would like to see your attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using `regexp_replace()` seems highly curious.  But you can use `translate()`:

```
select translate(col, 
                 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
                 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                )
```